# My method is running twice when it is only called once

Tags: java

So i am calling a method makeCard(String info) from another class. It works fine the first time it runs through but the second time i call on the method it seems to run twice which creates a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException runtime error and i can't seem to figure out why. I am a bit new to Java so i may be missing something obvious but the logic in my head says it should only run once if called once. Hopefully someone can point out my error.

Here is the method:

```
public void makeCard(String info){
    cInfo = new StringBuffer(info);
    int i = 0;

    while(cInfo.charAt(i)== ' '){
        cInfo.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
    while(cInfo.charAt(cInfo.length()-1)== ' '){
        cInfo.deleteCharAt(cInfo.length()-1);
        i--;
    }
    seperateValues();
    makeObject();
}
```

and here is where it is called:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    CardBreakdown cb = new CardBreakdown();
    if("submit".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
        cb.makeCard(cardInfo.getText());
        mw.removeAddPanel();
        cardInfo.setText("");
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

this is the error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Comment: can u post the exact error msg?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.StringBuffer.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at CardBreakdown.makeCard(CardBreakdown.java:24)
 at EnterCard.actionPerformed(EnterCard.java:62)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: I wouldn't use StringBuffer, ever.  I would use `info.trim()` which will do what you want.

Comment: You are not getting that exception in the mode you posted. Post the exception stack trace and the current code.

Comment: mig, please do not fix the code in the question - it invalidates all the answers and makes the Q/A useless for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

The *first* thing I would be doing is replacing those two `while` loops in `makeCard()` with a simple call to [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) - that function will remove leading and trailing whitespace for you.

You should generally always prefer a library call to crafting your own functions, *especially* functions that may have a rather fatal flaw when, for example, handling empty strings or strings which consist only of spaces :-)

There is no checking in either of your loops for the case where the string is or becomes empty, meaning that `charAt` will complain bitterly.

Answer (score 1):

What if info was empty or null? Then cInfo.charAt(0) will return the error you are getting. You should a null or empty check at the start of your makeCard method

Comment: An empty check is reasonable, but throwing a `NullPointerException` would be entirely reasonable for a `null` input.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unnecessarily convoluted for simply removing all occurrences of the space character from a string. Instead:

```
cInfo = info.trim();
```

Comment: there are other spaces in the stringbuffer that i wish to keep but thanks for the tip

Comment: Then why the first loop, which erases all spaces from it? Also, use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: The first loop does an `ltrim()` as it stops when it encounters the first non-space.

Comment: @mig Updated answer to do what I think you want.

Comment: @chrylis i agree that change is definitely more efficient, thanks for that but i am still getting an error because the method is running twice on the second time it is called, i don't understand why it would run a second time

Comment: @mig The exception you're getting has nothing to do with how many times the method is getting called. If it were called multiple times and the logic were correct, you wouldn't get the exception, and if it's called once with your erroneous loop condition (empty string?), it'll throw. Use `trim()`, and the problem should go away.

Comment: @chrylis i did initiate the change you suggested, and when sending through the same string twice, it works the first time it runs but not the second: i showed updated code above